# Laravel 5.2 Get date difference using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-5, indexing, eloquent, undefined

I'm trying to get the date_diff of queried data using query builder, yet I can't pass the 'create_at' values to count the days difference. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Staff;
class StaffController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $currentdate = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s');
        $trialusers=Staff::all('id','email','created_at','trial')->where('trial',1);
        $datediff = date_diff($trialusers['created_at'],$currentdate);
        return $datediff;
    }
}
```

Database

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trial      | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$trialusers` actually contains any data when you do the date comparison?

Comment: the `$trialusers` only shows `'id','email','created_at','trial'`

Comment: Not relevant. Is there any data at all in it? When you call `Staff::all()` is it returning any data?

Comment: Yes, it shows all the data when I call `Staff::all();` from `staffs table`

Comment: `date_diff` doesn't take dates as strings, it takes them as `DateTime` objects.

Comment: in your model set `$timeStamp =false`

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, I've noticed that, my bad! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually by using this code:

```
$trialusers=Staff::all('id','email','created_at','trial')->where('trial',1);
```

the $trialusers variable will be a collection of Staff models. So you can't access array keys like $trialusers['created_at'].

You either have to do a foreach loop or fetch the first model of the collection. This example uses the first() method.

```
public function index()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $trialusers = Staff::all('id','email','created_at','trial')->where('trial',1);

    $trialuser = $trialusers->first();
    if ($trialuser) {
        return $now->diffInDays($trialuser->created_at);
    }

    // do whatever needs to be done when no trial user exists.
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this idea. I just do the for loop and store the vaues in array. Instead of using carbon I just use the regular date_today(format). Will post my codes.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to better use Carbon library: so your code should look like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Staff;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    class StaffController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $currentdate = Carbon::create();
            $trialusers=Staff::all('id','email','created_at','trial')->where('trial',1);
            $date = $trialusers->created_at;
            $datediff = $date->diffInDays($currentdate);
            return $datediff;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also as others tell you, you could dd($trialusers) to check if your query are not returning a null valor for the created_at row before

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out -> Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved my problem. First I for loop the data with the condition where **trial = 1** . Second is to validate the date of **create_at** and make comparison with date today by N days. Last I made a condition to filter data by N days **(6 days diff and 7 days diff)** then store it in array. I'll be using those **$trialuser6** and **$trialuser7**  variables to create a function for email notification.

Thanks, I really appreciate all the ideas and suggestion.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Mail;
use App\User;

class checkTrial extends Command
{


    public function checkTrialUser()
    {
        $trialuser6 = [];
        $trialuser7 = [];
        foreach (User::all()->where('trial', 1) as $value) {
            $differtrial = !$this->validateDate($value['created_at']) ? 0 : (int) date_diff(date_create($value['created_at']), date_create(date('Y-m-d')))->format('%a');
            $differtrial == 6 ? array_push($trialuser6, $value) : ($differtrial == 7 ? array_push($trialuser7, $value) : null);
        }
    }

}
```

My validation function.

```
    public function validateDate($date)
    {
        return (bool) strtotime($date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Staff;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class StaffController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $currentdate = Carbon::create();
        $trialusers=Staff::all('id','email','created_at','trial')->where('trial',1)->->first();
        if($trialusers){
            $date = $trialusers->created_at;
            $datediff = $date->diffInDays($currentdate);
            return $datediff;
        }else{
           return null;
        }

    }
}
```